# Linear algebra characteristic values of non zero matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $c$ is characteristic value of $n\times n$ matrix $A$, then how to prove that $A-cI_n$ is singular, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix?

Comment: In some cases this is the definition of a "characteristic value", also known as an eigenvalue.  How do you define "characteristic value"?

Comment: It is the value of c for which there exist a n×1 matrix X such that AX=cX....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(R)$ and let $c\in R$ be a eigenvalue (charateristic value) of $A$, then there exists $X\in R^n\setminus\{0_{R^n}\}$ such that: $$AX=cX.$$
Therefore, $$(A-cI_n)X=0_{R^n}.$$
In other words, $X\in\textrm{ker}(A-cI_n)$ and since $X\neq 0_{R^n}$, $\textrm{ker}(A-cI_n)\neq\{0_{R^n}\}$ and $A-cI_n$ is singular.